# Which spirits can only be obtained by summoning?

Tags: super-smash-bros-ultimate

In Super Smash Bros. Ultimate, it is possible to summon spirits. Some of the summonable spirits are also obtainable in the World of Light (adventure mode), in various shops, and/or on the Spirit Board.

**Which spirits can be obtained exclusively by summoning?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Source: [All Summon-exclusive Spirits](https://www.reddit.com/r/smashbros/comments/a9avbu/all_summonexclusive_spirits/)

#### Attack

- Xander
- Raiden
- Samurai Goroh
- Ephraim
- Shadow Queen
- Burrowing Snagret
- Masked Dedede
- Kyurem (Black Kyurem)
- Daroach
- Dillon
- Rodin
- Scizor
- King Bob-Omb
- The Wandering Samurai

### Shield

- Galacta Knight
- Dyna Blade
- Octopus
- Proto Man
- Absolutely Safe Capsule
- Demise
- Cat Peach
- Baron K. Roolenstein
- Ruto
- Kyurem (White Kyurem)
- Jimmy T.
- Cordelia
- Spyke

### Grab

- Master Cycle
- Super Macho Man
- Resetti
- Pit (Original)
- Queen Sectonia
- Micaiah
- Birdo
- Knuckles
- Louie
- Barbara the Bat
- Dixie Kong
- Andross (Star Fox)
- Wonder-Red
- Ribbon Girl

### Neutral

- Master Core
- Yellow Devil
- Paper Mario
- Plasm Wraith
- Starfy
- Fusion Suit
- Shadow Mario
- Koume & Kotake
- Yung & Yang
- D.J. Octavio
- Mr. Shine & Mr. Bright
- Tom Nook
- DJ K.K.

### Support

- Gold Mario
- Super Happy Tree
- Great Fox
- Jirachi
- Judd
- Squid Sisters
- Epona
- Moon
- Mr. Saturn
- Ultimate Chimera
- Hector (Fire Emblem)
- Chef (Game & Watch)
- Phosphora
- Mona
- Pete
- Tortimer
- Blathers
- Rush
- Tree (Wii Fit)
- Mother Fairy
- Dhalsim
- Inkling Squid
- Julius Belmont
- Thwomp
- Nabbit
- Sprixie Fairies
- Cappy
- Professor Elvin Gadd
- Togepi
- Jet the Hawk
- Sonic the Werehog
- Phyllis & Pelly
- Warrior (Wii Fit)
- Formula
- E. Honda
- Ibuki
- Flow
- Jill & The Drill Dozer
- Ninjara

Note that once you summon these spirits, they have a chance to appear on the Spirit Board.

Comment: This list from Reddit is NOT correct. It includes some spirits that can be obtained by other methods. For example Hector can be obtained from Spirit Board before being summoned.

Comment: @MBorg There was a recent Fire Emblem event and you can find spirits that would normally have to be unlocked through summons first on the Spirit Board during these events.

Comment: In that case, the list seems correct. I also was initially caught off guard when I saw Andross (Star Fox) on the list, but then I realised it was actually Andross (Star Fox 64) that was obtainable through Adventure Mode